# Equal statement for Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, equals, if-statement

I am withdrawing from the database a page name and putting into the this equal statement:

```
 // Redirect if not there
 if ($db_client === $session_client) {
 require("custom.php");
 } else {
 require("general.php");
 }
```

So here, $db_client is the client id stored for a custom page and $session_client being the id in the session.  If it matches it should take the user to custom.php and if not it should take them to general.php

For some reason PHP shows me both pages.  general.php on top and custom.php at the bottom of the general.php

I am using this on general page:

```
  // If not page (path) is stored in db than show general
  if (empty($pagename)) {

   require_once("general.php");

  } else {
  require_once("$pagename");

  }
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Could you explain a little more of what's going on here? What do you mean by "redirect"?

Comment: @AAA could this code be called twice by something else? also you might want to use `require_once()` so that if this code is called twice you don't have two of the same thing show up.

Comment: @compeek redirect meaning echoing contents of the page.  ignore that //comment

Comment: @middaparka i thought you have to use === versus ==

Comment: @patrick yes it seems because its doing this twice, one time to make sure there is no empty path and second to authenticate page owner.  is there a way i can integrate them into one?

Comment: This is slightly tangental, but "require" and "require_once" are not functions, they're keywords, so you don't need the parenthesis. Ie: `require "custom.php"`. As for your question, can you post the rest of your script, where it's calling the code twice?

Comment: @AAA to prevent this code from including both of the required files you *should* find out why it's running twice and fix it, but if that fails, you can set a variable inside both the required files and then when you are checking which file to require you can use `isset()` to find if either of the two files has already executed.

Comment: @AAA I hope you know `===` is different from `==`

Comment: @kumar what are the differences?

Comment: Not sure if you have read this, http://in3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be in a different place than you think. Especially since we know that general.php could be included in several places.

So you need to get the actual order of includes to **locate** the problem.

Option A. Install xdebug module and you'll be able to get the log of every call.

Option B is simpler. Write `echo 'including-', <N>;` before every require operator. `<N>` is the number, unique for every usage. So you'll be able to know which operator caused the unwanted include.

BTW. Isn't `require_once($pagename);` better than `require_once("$pagename");`?
And ensure `$pagename` variable is secured against the relative path attacks.

Comment: instead of using numbers use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macros for this type of debugging, in case of classes I use `__METHOD__` and `__FUNCTION__` for procedural code